# Map in aggregation in MONGODB with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My DB Collection is look like this:

```
    {
    province: 1
    }
    {
    province: 2
    }
    {
    province:3
    },
    {
    province:4
    },
```

Now I want to map value of province to name of the province in aggregation in Mongodb.

**Expected Output**:

```
{
        province: "ab"// In database value of province is 1
},
{
        province: "cd"// In database value of province is 2
},
{
        province: "ef"// In database value of province is 3 
},
{
        province: "gh"// In database value of province is 4 
}
```

Comment: I think you should do this mapping on the application level, as DB has no responsibility of this

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches here. In this case of consecutive numbers (or enum), you can do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {provinceNames: ["o", "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      province: {$arrayElemAt: ["$provinceNames", "$province"]}
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4qbfgUEW8H_)

Comment: It serves his request, but this is far a way from clean solution, and I don't think there is one

Comment: I agree that this is not clean, but I don't judge the request. We only see a very narrow context here.

Comment: No luck, because It simply displays me the ["o", "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]. But All i want is to map these province name on value which is stored in my DB. For-example: ` "ab" should be mapped on "1"(which is stored in DB)` etc

Comment: I don't follow. This gives your expected output. Do you want to take the map from your db? Is it on another collection? do you have a mapping object?

Comment: Yes,I have map object.

Comment: Where is it then?